# Node: Insert string of special characters in mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, tcp

I am implementing fingerprint authentication for my angular app using node tcp server in my scenario the bio metric device return the string of special characters to my node server which includes special characters like single and double like `@#$'%"` i wanted to store this complete string to database with single as well as double quotes. i have following query

```
var fingerPrint = '@#$'%"'
db.query("insert into tbl_name (id, tempalte) value ('"+fingerPrint+"','')", (err, result)=>{
console.log(result)
})
```

but when string contain double quotes the query terminates as well as the problem with single quote. is there is any way to achieve this mechanism.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of `'` use `\'`

Comment: no i dont want to change meaning its fingerprint which converted to string. suppose i remove any of this special character of added or use escape character it will change entire meaning of fingerprint then it is hard to match

Comment: Ok but `'@#$'%"'`, this doesn't work. You need to use `'@#$\'%"'`. Like that, js see all your characters.

Comment: yes i know but this is biggest challenge to store each and every character to db

Comment: I don't understand, if you know that your code is wrong and you don't want to correct, don't ask, please.

Comment: dear i know what i am asking is for suggestions like can i convert this string to buffer or blob anything like this i know this escape character is important in this situation but i have some limitation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using MySQL in NodeJs. This is what you can try:

```
let fingerPrint = `'@#$'%"'`;
let addQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_name (id, template) VALUES (?,?)";
let values = [1, fingerPrint];

db.query(addQuery, values, function (err, result) {
   if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
   }
   console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
})
```

Comment: I have tested it recently. It's still working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
encodeURI() and decodeURI() it may work
```

Comment: it will change the meaning of because the string is made up of fingerprint expression encode uri add some extra fields in string

Comment: When you use decodeuri it will give original string

Comment: what does encodeURI impact to single quote or double quote?